# How to animate consecutively using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation

I would like to animate these dots consecutively. If sample1 dot is 100%, the sample2 will animate to 100%, then the sample3 will be next to animate.

[image]

I'm trying to write the code, but failed. The output of my code is all dots animate together.

Here is my code

```
var previous = null;
$(".myblock").each(function(){
  var a = $(this); 
  if(previous){
     a.find("span").animate({ left: "100%"},1000,function(){
      $(this).attr("rel","100");
    });
  }else{
  var d =  $(this).prev().find("span").attr("rel");
     a.find("span").animate({ left: "100%"},1000,function(){
      $(this).attr("rel","100");
    });
  }

  previous = this;

});
```

If you have tutorial like this. please give me links. I'm doing an experiment if this is applicable in jQuery.

**Update**

My html

```
<div class="block-row">
<div class="myblock">
     <label>sample1</label>
     <div class="block-rate">
       <span></span>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="myblock">
     <label>sample2</label>
        <div class="block-rate">
            <span></span>
        </div>
     </div>
<div class="myblock">
      <label>sample3</label>
        <div class="block-rate">
              <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my CSS

```
.block-row{
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.block-rate {
    background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 3px;
    position: relative;
}
.myblock{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.block-row label{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.block-rate span{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -10px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: if you could post your html/css it'd be great

Comment: I update my post @SantiagoHernández

Comment: cool thanks, take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var elements = $(".myblock span").toArray().reverse();
var animateNext = function() {
    if(elements.length > 0) {
        $(elements.pop()).animate({ left: "100%"},1000, animateNext);
    }
}
animateNext();
```

```css
.block-row{
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.block-rate {
    background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 3px;
    position: relative;
}
.myblock{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.block-row label{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.block-rate span{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -10px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-row">
<div class="myblock">
     <label>sample1</label>
     <div class="block-rate">
       <span></span>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="myblock">
     <label>sample2</label>
        <div class="block-rate">
            <span></span>
        </div>
     </div>
<div class="myblock">
      <label>sample3</label>
        <div class="block-rate">
              <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is this what they call callback function?

Comment: yup the third argument of `$(selector).animate()` is a callback function, its called when the animation ends

Comment: well the magic relies on [`$().toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/), [`Array.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) and [`Array.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

Comment: Better to add description in the answer. Code only answers are most likely to be downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `.animate()` and `.fadeIn()` accepts a call back so you can

```
$('#div1').animate({top:100}, 1500, function() {
    $('#div2').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        $('#div3').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Heres another example I found off here, which is pretty straightforward. See [Start animation only after first is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132982/how-to-start-one-jquery-animation-only-after-another-is-totally-complete)

```
$('.search-toggle').on('click', function(){
    $("body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow", function(){
        $('.search-drawer').slideToggle(); // or fadeIn(), show() ect..
    });
});
```

You could also try toying with the `.delay()` Which could kind of have the "one after the other" effect like the following [Start animation one after the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379900/fade-in-each-element-one-after-another)

```
$("span").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(400*index).fadeIn(300);
});
```

If you can post a fiddle of your code I can try giving you an example :)

Comment: I update my post. I will the try delay(). maybe delay will help me.